# MySQL online testing tool

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

is there an online tool for MySQL (or just SQL) that lets me quickly test some ideas that come to my mind randomly?

Like JSFiddle for HTML/CSS/JS
Or http://writecodeonline.com/php/ for PHP?

Something like this but for MySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Yup. How do I vote "+" for a comment?

Comment: Don't vote for a comment. We are closing this question, because there are millions like them.

Comment: @user2394156 if you move your mouse next to the comment (to the left), you will see a little up-arrow :) , anyway, for sharing / saving PHP fiddles, I recommend ideone.com - it is not that fast, but has much more features.

Comment: I found this site pretty much helping. 
http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_basics 
Although they use mariaDB still same queries.. So no worries.

Comment: `sqlfiddle.com`: some time give error: `Oops! Something went wrong. Try it again and if this keeps happening, email admin@sqlfiddle.com about it.`

Comment: In my order of personal preference: http://rextester.com/, http://sqlfiddle.com/, http://sqlize.com/, https://sqltest.net/. (Also http://dbfiddle.uk/ doesn't support MySQL but does support MariaDB if that's any good.)

Comment: SQL fiddle or sqltest.net are MyiSAM or INNODB ?

Answer (score 44):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://sqltest.net/

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot. Maybe someone knows other tools like this?

Comment: seems that sqltest.net is better, because sqlfiddle.com converts decimal values into float/double which is BAD.

Comment: Apparently it still doesn't work with MySql 8.*

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com works with MySql 8.*

Comment: Is it MyiSAM or INNODB ?

Comment: This website is pretty good for testing also

https://paiza.io/en/languages/mysql

Comment: https://sqliteonline.com/